# Challenging db table and query

Tags: sql, postgresql, between

I am having some challenging times with an sql query. I use Postgresql to begin with.

I have a table where I keep "Not Available" items information of a real time service results if I cannot get any result from a specific. I have starting and ending time of getting results for every item.

If I cannot get any result starting from yesterday to now, I update the row of item ID's start_time to yesterday and end_time to now. If I start getting results I update the end_time to the timestamp I start getting results. After that point, I leave that row. If I start getting NaN results again, I insert a new row with the new timestamp.

I know it is kind of a complicated process of updating a table, that's why I am here.

What I want to do with this table is this: I need to get the count of Not Available items for a specific time range such as between two days ago and yesterday.

So here is my query:

```
select count(*) 
from (
select item_id from nan_value_report 
where 
start_time >=  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '2 days'
and end_time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '1 days'
and value = 'NaN' 
group by item_id)
```

I know I don't include NaN results of items which have started two days ago and still continuing now. I need to include them in my result as well. Efficiency is another challenge as well, this table contains 9M rows.

Thanks in advance.

> ```
>           Item Id                          Start time        End time
> ```
>
> "1890857284";60310;;;;"";"";"23:55";"2014-11-14
>   12:25:00";"2014-11-15 12:20:00";0
>   "1895585118";114290;;;;"";"";"23:55";"2014-11-11
>   01:55:00";"2014-11-13 01:50:00";0
>   "1831040276";110582;;;;"";"";"23:55";"2014-11-11
>   06:10:00";"2014-11-13 06:05:00";0
>   "1890866637";62645;;;;"";"";"23:55";"2014-11-12
>   16:05:00";"2014-11-13 16:00:00";0
>   "1890865290";59356;;;;"";"";"23:55";"2014-11-15
>   01:45:00";"2014-11-16 01:40:00";0
>   "1890858847";56783;;;;"";"";"23:55";"2014-11-14
>   12:25:00";"2014-11-15 12:20:00";0
>   "1890866262";57834;;;;"";"";"23:55";"2014-11-14
>   12:25:00";"2014-11-15 12:20:00";0

---

I've come up with the idea to use OR to include the results I couldn't include with the previous one. It is a bit slow but it works:

```
select count(*) from
(select this.item_id
from nan_value_report this 
where 
(this.start_time >=  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '3 days' and this.end_time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP            - interval '2 days') or
(this.start_time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '2 days' and this.end_time >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '2 days')
group by this.item_id, this.value
having this.value = 'NaN');
```

Let me know if you have more efficient solutions.

Comment: did you consider using timestamp ranges? Since you are using postgres why not use it its features.

Comment: Would it be more efficient? I will give it a try.

Comment: You can use GIST indexes on ranges ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) grand_total, 
sum( case when value='NaN' then 1 else 0 end) NAN_TOTAL,
sum( case when value != 'Nan' then 1 else 0 end) NON_NAN_TOTAL,
from nan_value_report 
where 
this.start_time >=  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '2 days'
and this.end_time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '1 days'
and value = 'NaN'
```

I don't fully understand you question, so I removed the "group by" -- you can add it back if it helps, but perhaps the syntax I'm using will help give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Group by is another parameter to get the right results, I didn't want to go into to not to confuse you more :) This query gives me only the count of my result. What I need is the + count of items with NaN value where its time is in range of my query. Maybe this last sentence will give you an idea.

Comment: I think we might need some example data for me to understand what you're wanting.
The query I gave you is a count of all rows within your date range + a count of NAN's within your date range + a count of all non NANs in your date range. but it's a count of the rows, not the "distinct item ids"
Are you wanting a count of the distinct item ids?

Comment: Hey Joe. I've added some sample data. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on your time range constraints.  *If* you want a distinct list of item_ids in the nan_value_report where the `(start_date..end_date)` interval overlaps with the `(2 day ago..1 day ago)` interval, you are just using the wrong logic overlap logic.  You should have

```
WHERE start_time < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '1 day')
  AND   end_time > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '2 days')
```

This will match everything were there's a time between `start_date` and `end_date` that's also between 1 and 2 days ago.

Comment: Hello Ramfjord, the where statement you propose gets results started 1 day ago and end after 2 days, missing results that has started 2 days ago and and before 1 day + still ongoing results which have started already and finished after that range. Thanks.

Comment: Your wording makes your comment difficult to follow, but I'll try to go through your examples:

`(-1 day ... +2 days)` fails because start_time >= -1 days (in this =), while 

`(-2 days ... -1.5 days)` succeeds.  Of course, if you want the first to pass, you can use `<=` instead of `<` in the where clause.